# How to unwrap Swift optional and cast type at the same time using guard?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code. the `response.result.value` is of type `Optional(AnyObject)`, I want to check

1. it's of type `[[String: AnyObject]]`
2. unwrap the optional
3. check the count of the array
4. I prefer one line guard over if...return... statement

   ```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, API.listArticle).responseJSON { response in
       print(response.result.value)

       guard let articles = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] where articles.count > 0 else {
           return
       }

       for article in articles {
           let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Article", inManagedObjectContext: DBHelper.context()) as! Article
           entity.title = article["title"]
           entity.content = article["content"]

       }
   }
   ```

The error is `article["content"]` line:

> Cannot subscript a value of type Dictionary<String, AnyObject> with an index of type String

Also do I need to check if `title` exist in `article`? Is it gonna crash or just do nothing?

Comment: Try iterating trough it using enumerate()

Comment: articles[jndex]["content"]

Comment: why is `for in` loop not working

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are using a dictionary where the `value` has type `AnyObject` to populate the `title` and the `content` properties that are probably `String` (right?)

You cannot put something that (at compile time) is declared `AnyObject` into a `String` property.

Just replace this

```
entity.title = article["title"]
entity.content = article["content"]
```

with this

```
entity.title = article["title"] as? String
entity.content = article["content"] as? String
```

### Update

This updated for will discard articles where the `title` and `content` values are not correct Strings.

```
for article in articles {

     if let
         title = article["title"] as? String,
         content = article["content"] as? String {

         let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Article", inManagedObjectContext: DBHelper.context()) as! Article

         entity.title = title
         entity.content = content
     }
}
```

Comment: content property would need to be optional String

Comment: Add ?? "" to make it non optional

Comment: what if `article["title"]` is not a string, or if `title` does not exist? is it gonna do anything?

Comment: Nil coalescing operator

Comment: @LeoDabus: you are right, I updated my answer to manage that scenario.

Comment: if title does not exist, i still want to create the article (without title). It seems tedious to use multiple `if let` statements

Comment: Is the title property optional?

Comment: @OMGPOP if your dictionary it is actually String:String you could try casting to [[String:String]] instead of [[String:AnyObject]]